# What is the most destructive spell in Harry Potter world?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

As the title says, what is the most destructive spell in the Harry Potter world?

In *Harry Potter and Deathly Hallows Part II*, the *Confringo* spell which is used by Voldemort seems to be the most destructive spell. Are there any stronger spell?

I mean causing great destruction. Great explosion and such. Not to human, but to an object.

Comment: I suspect the answer to this will simply be “we don’t know.” It might even be a little too opinion-based, due to the vagueness of the word “destructive.” For example, *Confringo* might have a higher rate of damage, Fiendfyre might be able to spread indefinitely, *Sectumsempra* might be harder to repair, and so forth. There are also book/movie distinctions to be considered.

Comment: Well, I mean cause a great destruction. Great explosion and such. Not to human, but to object.

Comment: Reducto or bombarda (?)

Comment: I'd say Bombarda Maxima is pretty "explosive". When Umbridge uses it in OotP, it causes a pretty sizeable explosion. I think that's movie-exclusive though, she doesn't do that in the book.

Comment: is it better if I change my question to "What is the most Explosive spell in Harry Potter world?" ?

Answer (score 1):

In the books, the most 'explosive' spell that we know of is either the *Reducto* spell, or *Expulso*.

In *GOF*, Harry uses the Reductor Curse to burn a hole through the hedge in the Third task. And in *OOTP*, Dumbledore's Army uses it to blast the bookcase of Time-Turners. (In the movie, it's only Ginny.)

[image: ginnyblasting]

In *DH*, a Death Eater, Antonin Dolohov, uses the *Expulso* Curse to blow up a table, causing Harry to drop his wand and the Invisibility Cloak to slip off as the force throws him into the wall.

> the table behind which Harry was standing blew up: the force of the explosion slammed him into the wall and he felt his wand leave his hand as the cloak slipped off him.

Comment: I prefer answer from the movies. (Ginny is awesome :D)